# how to check edittext's input frquently?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

i have an Edit text and a textview. In the Edit text user will give a value and based on that the Text view will show the result of a calculation. But there will be no button. how can i check the values of the input in the edit text frequently and after calculation show them in text box automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) to your `EditText` to verify and calculate text. For example:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Further, you may update the text of your `TextView` in **afterTextChanged** method.